# i'm wanting onChange to keep generate id ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have function makeid

```js
const makeid = (length) => {
  var result = "";
  var characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
};
```

and i have function createArray use makeid

```js
const createArray = (x) => {
  let array = [];
  const object = {
    id: makeid(5),
  };
  for (let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    array.push(object);
  }
  return array;
};
```

& I create func nummberOfColumns

```js
let a = [];
[...studentObject, ...createArray((5 -studentObject.length)].map((ele) => {
      a.push({
        id: ele.id,
        });
});
return a
```

then I use number Of Columns.map() to return the `</th>` tag. In this tag I use onChange, but every time onChange the id changes to another id, I don't want that to happen. I tried using Usememo but it didn't work.

Comment: please add your code for the React component as well

Comment: Also map creates an array: `return [...studentObject, ...createArray((5 -studentObject.length)].map(({id}) => id);`

Comment: Where are you calling your numberOfColumns method? Is it inside the render function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `useEffect` with an empty dependencies array (`[]`). There, initiate all your code and attach the result to a state. You can use `useState` to manage that. It's happening because on each change in a tree, all the subtree re-renders. `useEffect` with an empty array **only** runs after mounting and first update (layout and paint). If you want to use `useMemo`, make sure to pass an empty array as well to prevent from re-calculation when a dependency changes.

`useEffect(function(), [])`

`useMemo(function(), [])`